# Spring Gateway builds incorrect URL with query string parameters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring gateway microservices with this mapping:

```
  - id: advertisementService4
    uri: lb://advertisementService
    predicates:
      - Path=/public/breeds/**
    filters:
      - RewritePath=/public/breeds/(?<segment>/?.*), /v1/public/breeds/$\{segment}
```

If I make a call with Postman to this url: http://192.168.99.1:8050/public/breeds/500, the gateWay service solves the mapping and build the new url in the correct way (to /v1/public/breeds/500):

[image]

But if I call to this url http://192.168.99.1:8050/public/breeds?petType=Dog, the gateWay service chooses the correct mapping, but it builds the url in a incorrect way:

[image]

The gateWay service builds http://7a32a826ec7a:8070/public/breeds?petType=Dog instead of  http://7a32a826ec7a:8070/v1/public/breeds?petType=Dog (with **v1** in the URL)

I don't understand why. Could you help me please?

Comment: Your rewrite path expression requires a trailing slash

Comment: Thanks for your answer @spencergibb ! How should be that?

Comment: And why gateway builds the url ok in the first call?

Comment: The first call has a slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it changing the RewritePath:

**from** RewritePath=/public/breeds/(?/?.*), /v1/public/breeds/${segment}

**to** RewritePath=/(?/?.*), /v1/${segment}